# Schlechtes Gewissen vs Gewissensbisse. Unterschiede

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung zwischen **"schlechtem Gewissen"** und **"Gewissensbissen"**?

Und wenn ja, worin unterscheiden sie sich in ihrer Bedeutung?

Comment: Die Frage finde ich sehr ungenau formuliert? Das persönliche Gefühl jeweils lässt sich nur schwer generalisieren. Geht es dir um die sprachliche Herkunft? Eine mögliche inhaltlich unterschiedliche Bedeutung?

Comment: Danke. Ich meinte den Inhalt bzw. Bedeutung und vielleicht dadurch Unterschied in der Verwendung. D.h. sind das Synonyme?

Answer (score 1):

In meinem Sprachgebrauch: Nein. Ich würde beide Begriffe in der Bedeutung synonym verwendet. Lediglich aus dem Kontext heraus entscheide ich, welche Formulierung ich wähle. **Schlechtes Gewissen** ist für mich förmlicher als **Gewissensbisse**. Letzteres würde ich eher im Umgang mit Freunden benutzen.

Ein Beispiel, wo ich es ähnlich handhaben würde ist für mich:

**sich ärgern / sich in den Hintern beißen**

(um bei der Beiß-Thematik zu bleiben :-))

Zu meinem Chef würde ich niemals sagen:

> Da beißt du dir bestimmt in den Hintern, dass du den Deal nicht abgeschlossen hast!

sondern eher sowas wie

> Da ärgerst du dich bestimmt.../Das ist ärgerlich...

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe einen Kommentar von dir gelöscht, weil er unfreundlich ist, und damit gegen den Code of Conduct dieser Seite verstößt. Bitte achte darauf, einen freundlichen Umgangston an den Tag zu legen.

Comment: Das war ein ganz sachlicher Kommentar, keine Unfreundlichkeit war damit verbunden, solange der Leser nicht egozentrisch ist.

Answer (score 0):

Beides kann man mehr oder weniger in gleicher Bedeutung verwenden, wobei ich persönlich sagen würde, dass man die Gewissensbisse vor der Tat hat und das schlechte Gewissen danach, allerdings gibt's auch genug Zitate, wo das Gewissen nach der Tat beißt.

Comment: M.E. kann man beides nur nach der Tat haben. Man kann antizipieren, dass man Gewissensbisse haben wird, aber so lange man nichts getan (oder unterlassen) hat ...

Comment: Man kann auch Gewissenbisse haben bevor oder während man eine Tat ausführt, beim schlechten Gewissen wäre mir das eher neu. Also im Sinne von Skrupel oder so.

Comment: Man kann durchaus sagen, dass man etwas nur mit schlechtem Gewissen tun wird.